# Ubuntu 20.04: Dual monitor docks - set them in center of both monitors

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-dock

After setting the dock on both monitors, I would like to change its position:

- Left side for the Right monitor
- Right side for the Left monitor

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know a gnome dock is a single instance, which can be "mirrored" on different screens. See it as a "live copy" per screen, so not changeable on one screen only

Comment: I indeed couldn't find this info anywhere and was hoping -even it was unlikely- no one needed this before me :<